# iPhone built-in controller to display a collection of images in cool 3D landscape view

Tags: iphone, 3d

For some reason, I can't seem to locate the documentation for the above support within the foundation. I am talking about the view used by some applications to show a collection of images in a cool 3D view where you can flip through the set, much like the iPod application view of the albums.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for Cover Flow.  I believe it is an unpublished API.  However [Open Flow](http://fajkowski.com/blog/2009/08/02/openflow-a-coverflow-api-replacement-for-the-iphone/) is a viable replacement.

Answer (score -2):

OK, found it, it's called CoverFlow - but I also note that it appears that Apple considers this a private API and thus cannot be used for apps on the App Store - can anyone confirm that it is so?

Comment: Yes, it's still a private API but see your answer above.

Comment: Yes, It was.
But, Apple reversed their decision about Clicker app which made by Alex. Thats mean It's not using private API, It builts top of the Core Animation. So, you can use it.